# "Apply Now" dialog does not take into account updated CVs after dialog was opened

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Problem: "Preview PDF" in Careers Modal "apply now" dialog does not take into account any changes made since the modal was opened.

Steps to reproduce:

If you click on a job posting and click "apply now", the following modal pops up:

[image: apply now modal]

This modal has a link to "Edit" your CV, presumably so the most up to date version is available for the recruiter.

1. Open "Apply Now"
2. Edit CV by clicking on `Edit >>`. Edit in a new job/experience.
3. Click "Prevent this experience from showing in header."
4. Click "Preview PDF"
5. Note that the PDF does not have the up to date experience.
6. Close the modal dialog.
7. re-open modal dialog by clicking "apply now"
8. click "Preview PDF", it is up to date with the new experience.

Expected behavior: "Preview PDF" should reflect any changes since the Modal was opened; not just before it was opened.